# How to sort a column in a dataframe containing a list of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, sorting

I have a dataframe containing a column `id` associated with a column containing a list of dates. These columns can contain 1 or more dates, but they are not sorted. How can I sort each row of the column `dates` chronologically?

```
data = [
    [
        1,
        [
            "2017-12-06",
            "2017-12-05",
            "2017-12-06",
            "2018-01-03",
            "2018-01-04",
            "2017-11-24",
        ],
    ],
    [
        2,
        [
            "2017-12-06",
            "2017-12-05",
            "2017-12-06",
            "2019-01-03",
        ],
    ],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["id", "dates"])
df


id  dates
1   [2017-12-06, 2017-12-05, 2017-12-06, 2018-01-03, 2018-01-04, 2017-11-24]
2   [2017-12-06, 2017-12-05, 2017-12-06, 2019-01-03]
```

what I want (dates sorted chronologically):

```
id  dates
1   [2017-11-24, 2017-12-05, 2017-12-06, 2018-01-03, 2018-01-04]
2   [2017-12-05, 2017-12-06, 2019-01-03]
```

what I've tried (that has not worked):

```
f = lambda x: x.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
df["dates"].apply(f)
```

(this returns all `None`)

Answer (score 2):

Try to sort the lists *in-place*:

```py
df["dates"].apply(list.sort)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id                                                                     dates
0   1  [2017-11-24, 2017-12-05, 2017-12-06, 2017-12-06, 2018-01-03, 2018-01-04]
1   2                          [2017-12-05, 2017-12-06, 2017-12-06, 2019-01-03]
```